# Is there a way to restore application state after closing and relaunching the app?

Tags: ios

I'm aware of the app delegate methods :

```
optional func application(_ application: UIApplication, shouldSaveApplicationState coder: NSCoder) -> Bool
```

and

```
optional func application(_ application: UIApplication, shouldRestoreApplicationState coder: NSCoder) -> Bool
```

That allow an app to keep track of its state while the app is in the background but I'd like to know if there were some similar methods that would keep track of an app's state after it is closed.

A use case :

Let's take a web browser, a user has several tabs opened and decides to close the app, when he/she relaunches the app, he/she would see the tabs he had opened before.

Comment: Why do you say those methods are only used when the app goes into the background?  Why can't they be used when the app is closed too?

Comment: Are they ? I might be wrong...

Comment: What does the documentation say?  Also look at the [iOS App Life Cycle](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/TheAppLifeCycle/TheAppLifeCycle.html) and observe that the app goes through *background* on its way to *suspended* and *not running*.

Comment: Thanks, I just read the iOS App Life Cycle and that state changes scheme is really interesting but it doesn't say if the app state is kept when the app goes from *background* to *suspended*. Actually, the documentation is not really clear about that :  https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1623089-application
I actually just read this tuto : https://www.raywenderlich.com/117471/state-restoration-tutorial
( c.f. Enabling State Restauration section )